# Enviar uma mensagem via e-mail aos clientes que responderam ao form do meu site

Tags: php, formulário

Tenho o seguinte código para enviar as respostas de um formulário do meu site ao meu e-mail:

```
<?php

//
//Variáveis
$n_nome = $_POST['n-nome'];
$n_email = $_POST['n-email'];
$n_fone = $_POST['n-fone'];
$n_msg = $_POST['n-msg'];

$data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
$hora_envio = date('H:i:s');

//
// Configuração do e-mail
  $arquivo = "
<html>
    <h1>NOVA MENSAGEM RECEBIDA VIA SITE</h1>

    <p>Nome: <b>$n_nome</b></p>
    <p>E-mail: <b>$n_email</b></p>
    <p>Telefone: <b>$n_fone</b></p>
    <p>Mensagem: <br> <b>$n_msg</b></p>
</html>
";

//
//enviar
  $emailenviar = "meuemail@contato.com";
  $destino = $emailenviar;
  $assunto = "[SITE CONTATO] $n_nome";

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'From: Meu Site <naoresponda@contato.com>';

  $enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
  if($enviaremail){
  $mgm = "MENSAGEM RECEBIDA COM SUCESSO!";
  echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;URL='> "; // Configurar página de destino
  } else {
  $mgm = "ERRO AO RECEBER MENSAGEM!";
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;URL='>";
  }
?>
```

Agora, quando vou responder a mensagem em meu e-mail eu tenho que copiar o e-mail do formulário e colar no campo apropriado. Ele sempre tenta responder para o  Há como deixar pré-difinido que quando eu responder ele já coloque o `$n_email` como destinatário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `From:` deveria ser o remetente e não um email fixo:

```
$headers .= 'From: Meu Site <naoresponda@contato.com>';
```

Deveria ser:

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . $n_nome . ' <' . $n_email . '>';
```

Note que você também pode usar o `Reply-To:`, ou seja definir que o remetente é um, mas no momento de responder o `Reply-To` vai dar preferencia para o email nele definido (isto pode não funcionar em alguns clientes de email web mais arcaicos, como squiremail), então ficaria assim:

```
$headers .= "From: Meu Site <naoresponda@contato.com>\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $n_nome . ' <' . $n_email . '>';
```

Comment: Ok. Troquei para   `$headers .= 'From: $n_nome <$n_email>';`. Mas na hora de responder la no e-mail fica "De: $n_nome, com o e-mail: $n_email@srv64.main-hosting.eu".

Comment: @MarcosLichtenfels Você copiou exatamente como eu fiz, ou vc mudou as aspas?

Comment: Deu certo. Copiei exatamente sua resposta e funcionou. Obrigado!